# Java- make a scrollpane's size change to size of table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

right now I have a jtable wrapped inside of a jscrollpane...

```
Jtable table = new JTable(10,10);
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollpane.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
```

(for example)

I was wondering how you can avoid having to set the size of the scrollpane?  I can't get the scrollpane/table to show up without calling setBounds.  I would like the scrollpane to be whatever size the table is (but not bigger than some maximum value) so there isn't a big gray rectangle under the table because the scrollpane is a set size.  How to avoid setting a set size?

Comment: My recommendation: Learn to use the layout managers, and then use them. For more help, create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org), since this sort of problem easily lends itself to this.

Answer (score 1):

As Hovercraft Full Of Eels has suggested, the simplest solution would be to set the container's layout manager to something like `BorderLayout` and add the scroll pane to it...

The layout manager will automatically take care of positioning and sizing the scrollpane for you.

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details